# for loop to get more than one arguments

Tags: bash, array, variable

In python and some other programming languages, it is easy to get a vector instead of one variable everywhere and in loops. like python:

```
for variable in [[user1,pass1],[user2,pass2],[user3,pass3],...]
    print variable[0]
    print variable[1]
```

But how can I get two arguments in one cycle, in shell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might also use an arithmetic for loop like this:

```
a=(user1 pass1 user2 pass2)
for ((i=0; i<${#a[@]}; i+=2)); do
  echo "${a[i]}: ${a[i+1]}"
done
```

Answer (score 3):

In bash, you can create an array, but nested data structures are not supported. Therefore, you have to hack something yourself. For example, you can use a separator:

```
#! /bin/bash
for tuple in user1#pass1 user2#ls\;ls user3#pass#3 ; do
    user=${tuple%%#*}
    password=${tuple#*#}
    echo User $user
    echo Password $password
done
```

Just make sure the first value never contains the separator.

Or, use `set` with a flat list and `shift` the right number of members in each iteration:

```
#! /bin/bash
set -- user1 pass1 user2 ls\;ls user3 pass#3
while (( $# )) ; do
    user=$1
    password=$2
    shift 2
    echo User $user
    echo Password $password
done
```

Comment: As labeled [tag:bash], you can use the C-like `for` to avoid messing with `$@`: http://pastebin.com/Ygy3Cs0C

Comment: Your `[[ $1 ]]` condition will fail to loop to the end if you have an empty odd value, like `set -- user1 pass1 '' ls\;ls user3 pass#3`. Better use `(($#))` instead.

Comment: Regarding the `eval`, is better to avoid it when possible. Either by using `user="${tuple%%#*}"; password="${tuple#*#}"` or by using `IFS='#' read user password <<< "$tuple"`.

Answer (score 0):

I like perl for this stuff, you can call this from inside a bash script:

```
perl -e 'my %users= ("user1" => "pass1","user2" => "pass2");
         for ( sort keys %users)
         {
             print "$_\t$users{$_}\n";
         }'
```

Comment: the above is a perl hash and the one liner simply loops thru the hash and prints the contents.  Looks like the "$_" did not get printed, but in perl it's a special variable - The default input and pattern-searching space.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables